# Is it possible to check the last element in the applied template

Tags: xslt

I have to check the last element in the template applied on some element through  the  as below -

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::*[@depth='2']" />
```

Below is the template  to be applied -

```
<xsl:template match="sm:AudioNode[@depth='2']">
    <li>
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </a>
</li>
</xsl:template>
```

Now in this template i want to check if the element is last , add the `<xsl:attribute name="class"> last</xsl:attribute>`.

Is it possible to check the last element in the applied template ?
if  yes , please share the code .

**NOTE:**- i have a big XSLT logic inside this template so would not want to duplicate it for adding this attribute only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a template gets called on a node, the context position and size are set according to the node list you called applied templates to. So this should do what you're asking:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">last</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```